# HTTP error code: 302 when calling https webservice

Tags: web-services, ssl

I am trying to call a SOAP RPC style web service and getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 302:

This is a https web service and I have imported the certificate into cacerts thru browser  but getting same result. Please note that, I can consume a REST webservice from the same machine without importing the certificate.

What I am missing when calling a SOAP service? Is it my client issue or something need to be done on the server side. I have access to the server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

HTTP status code 302 is a redirect, and so is unlikely due to a certificate problem.  My initial guess is that you need to add a / (or remove it) from your URL.  Some http server frameworks will redirect when a resource does not end in a /, so, instead of:

```
GET /myRpcEndpoint
```

Try

```
GET /myRpcEndpoint/
```

The other possibility is that this resource requires authentication and the server is redirecting you to a login page.  If you want to know what is going on (and not guess), take a look a the the response headers for the 302.  There will be a Location header telling you where the server wants you to go instead.

Comment: Hi Eric - Thanks so much! I am using wsimport with the valid service wsdl (e.g. https://sa-sf.erp.net/testWSthree/service?wsdl). So, I guess url or location are good. About the other possibility, how can I see the response header? I am calling the service from a test client app in  eclipse.

Comment: Using HTTPWatch, I noticed that server is redirecting the response to http://sa-dev-sf.erp.net/testWSthree/service?wsdl. instead of https://.. and has following Header info in httpwatch: (Status-Line)  HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Connection close
Location https://sa-dev-sf.erp.net/testWSthree/service?wsdl

Comment: well, I think you figured it out yourself - the redirect is to http.  Reading between the lines, if this server is ASP.NET, I believe there is a configuration file (web.config?) that specifies which URLs are secured (https) and which are not.  Maybe it is as simple as finding the config file. But, I'm crummy with ASP so don't look too hard with my advice!

Comment: Hi Eric - Thanks so much for being so patient! This is a java application hosted in Apache Tomcat. Tomcat server has server.xml, context.xml, web.xml and other files. Server.xml file have an entry like this: <Connector port="8025" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />                                                                  But, the port 8443 (suppose to be ssl port) is commented out. Please help or let me know where I can get help. I am new in this area.

Comment: We are all new to everything at one point in time.  Unfortunately my Tomcat help is going to be even less useful than my .NET help. :(  Hopefully someone else will come along with some details.  Or you could create a new question with these new details.  Something like "Tomcat server redirecting https to http" and provide your config files and what you've tried.

Answer (score 4):

Had a similar issue where client code would receive a HTTP 302 error code when communicating with https and would work fine when communicating with http. In client code,you might need to specify the endpoint address on the request context using the BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY property. Following the JAX-WS paradigm, the example below should work.
Please note that only the BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY needs to be defined, the rest of your code should remain the same.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws {

    ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();

    GetProducts_Service service = new GetProducts_Service();
    GetProducts getProducts = service.getGetProductsPort();
    final BindingProvider getProductsBP = (BindingProvider) getProducts;
    getProductsBP.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
            "https://example.server.net/ExampleServicesWar/GetProducts");

    GetProductsRequest request = factory.createGetProductsRequest();        
    GetProductsResponse response=getProducts.getProducts(request);      
    List<Product> products=response.getProducts();

}
```

Comment: Hi Rami - Thanks so much for being helpful! I have changed my code accordingly. This is working fine when I am calling the service from Eclipse IDE. But when I call the exact same client deployed on our tomcat server ot is giving me error. javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: https:.... Please note that  I have created a separate thread for this issue. Please see if you can have any solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835441/receiving-http-302-error-code-when-communicating-with-https-web-service

Answer (score 3):

All you have to is to use correct end point url

```
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.
        ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "https://yourservice");
```

Need to import at the top:

```
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
```

port is Method call:

full source:

```
private static String getApplicationStatus(java.lang.String remoteAccessKey, java.lang.Integer responseId) {
    net.quotit.oes._2010.ws.applicationstatusupdate.OASStatusUpdateService service = new net.quotit.oes._2010.ws.applicationstatusupdate.OASStatusUpdateService();
    net.quotit.oes._2010.ws.applicationstatusupdate.IApplicationStatusUpdate port = service.getStatusUpdate();
    ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.
        ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "https://servicename/basic");

    return port.getApplicationStatus(remoteAccessKey, responseId);
}
```

Comment: Works like charm!