# Receiving HTTP 302 error code when communicating with https web service

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, https, jax-ws

I have a java web service hosted in Apache Tomcat. Tomcat Server.xml file have an entry like this:

```
Connector port="8025" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"
```

But,  the port 8443 (suppose to be ssl port) is commented out.

Using HTTPWatch, I noticed that server is redirecting the client request to http://sa-dev-sf.erp.net/testWSthree/service?wsdl. instead of https://.. and has following Header info in httpwatch: (Status-Line) HTTP/1.1 302 Found; Connection close Location sa-dev-sf.erp.net/testWSthree/service?wsdl

Here is my client test class. If I deploy the client in tomcat server and call the service I am getting error (See log below). Please note this is working fine from my local machine using Eclipse IDE

```
import a.Service;  //from wsimport
import a.ServiceImplService; //from wsimport

public class Call {
public String callTest(){  
    ServiceImplService serviceImpl = new ServiceImplService();
    Service s = serviceImpl.getServiceImplPort();
    final BindingProvider getResultBP = (BindingProvider) s ;
    getResultBP.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,"https://sa-dev.erp.xxxx.net/testWSthree/service");
    System.out.println(s.salaryUpgrade("sanjoy"));
}}
```

Here are the two classes generated by **wsimport**:

```
@WebService(name = "Service", targetNamespace = "http://a/")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public interface Service {
/**
 * @param name
 * @return returns java.lang.String
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "SalaryUpgrade")
@WebResult(partName = "return")
@Action(input = "http://a/Service/SalaryUpgradeRequest", output = "http://a/Service/SalaryUpgradeResponse")
public String salaryUpgrade(
    @WebParam(name = "name", partName = "name")
    String name);
}
```

and

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "ServiceImplService", targetNamespace = "http://a/", wsdlLocation = 
"https://sa-dev.erp.xxxxx.net/testWSthree/service?wsdl")
public class ServiceImplService extends javax.xml.ws.Service
{

private final static URL SERVICEIMPLSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
private final static WebServiceException SERVICEIMPLSERVICE_EXCEPTION;
private final static QName SERVICEIMPLSERVICE_QNAME = new QName("http://a/", "ServiceImplService");

static {
    URL url = null;
    WebServiceException e = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("https://sa-dev.erp.xxxxx.net/testWSthree/service?wsdl");
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        e = new WebServiceException(ex);
    }
    SERVICEIMPLSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    SERVICEIMPLSERVICE_EXCEPTION = e;
}

public ServiceImplService() {
    super(__getWsdlLocation(), SERVICEIMPLSERVICE_QNAME);
}

public ServiceImplService(WebServiceFeature... features) {
    super(__getWsdlLocation(), SERVICEIMPLSERVICE_QNAME, features);
}

public ServiceImplService(URL wsdlLocation) {
    super(wsdlLocation, SERVICEIMPLSERVICE_QNAME);
}

public ServiceImplService(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature... features) {
    super(wsdlLocation, SERVICEIMPLSERVICE_QNAME, features);
}

public ServiceImplService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
    super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
}

public ServiceImplService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature... features) {
    super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     returns Service
 */
@WebEndpoint(name = "ServiceImplPort")
public a.Service getServiceImplPort() {
    return super.getPort(new QName("http://a/", "ServiceImplPort"), Service.class);
}

/**
 * 
 * @param features
 *     A list of {@link javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature} to configure on the proxy.  Supported features not in the <code>features</code> parameter will have their default values.
 * @return
 *     returns Service
 */
@WebEndpoint(name = "ServiceImplPort")
public a.Service getServiceImplPort(WebServiceFeature... features) {
    return super.getPort(new QName("http://a/", "ServiceImplPort"), Service.class, features);
}

private static URL __getWsdlLocation() {
    if (SERVICEIMPLSERVICE_EXCEPTION!= null) {
        throw SERVICEIMPLSERVICE_EXCEPTION;
    }
    return SERVICEIMPLSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
}
}
```

**This is working fine when I am calling the web service from Eclipse IDE. But if I deploy this client app in our tomcat server and call the service, I am getting the following error:**

```
 Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

 root cause 
 javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: https://sa-dev.erp.xxxxx.net/testWSthree/service?wsdl. It failed with: 
Got sa-dev-sf.erp.umasscs.net while opening stream from https://sa-dev.erp.xxxxx.net  /testWSthree/service?wsdl.
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:173)
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:155)
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:120)
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:257)
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:220)
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:168)
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:96)
javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
a.ServiceImplService.<init>(ServiceImplService.java:41)
ws.callWS.Call.callTest(Call.java:26)
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:68)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

 root cause 
 java.io.IOException: Got sa-dev-sf.erp.umasscs.net while opening stream from https://sa-    dev.erp.xxxxx.net/testWSthree/service?wsdl

 com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:842)
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.resolveWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:283)
```

I really appreciate any help on this issue. Thanks you.

Comment: Where do you see status code 302? It doesn't appear in the log you have posted.

Comment: Hi Miljen, Thank you. I have used httpwatch and noticed that redirection.  I have edited the post and added the comment at the begining.

Comment: Do you have any confidentiality security constraints in your `web.xml`?

Comment: Web.xml for the web service is simple with no security constraint. Also, I haven't noticed any security constraint on tomcat's web.xml. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you import the ssl certificate in the trust store? It is possible that eclipse JVM have the certificate and your deployment did not.

openssl s_client -connect  -showcerts < /dev/null | openssl x509 -outform PEM > cert.pem
this command would download the certificate. You can  do that with any browser pointing to your web address of your server.

and list with : keytool -list -keystore   -storepass

If your certificate is not there you add it with : 
keytool -import -alias  -file derp.pem -keystore   -storepass